# ToString and Output issues

Tags: java, variables, int, tostring

I need some help with my program.

This is my assignment

[image]

I have already written the code but when I go to have my code printed out, it only prints out the Int. (Note my formatting is a lot better — I’m not used to this website).

This is my class file:

```
public class Card
{

  //instance variables
  public String rank;
  public String suit ;
  public int cardValue;

  //constructor

 public Card(String rank, String suit, int cardValue)
 {
  this.rank = rank;  
  this.suit = suit;
  this.cardValue = cardValue; 
 }

 //accessors
 //get methods

 public String getrank()   
 {     
 return rank;   
 }

 public String getsuit()
 {
 return suit; 
 }

 public int getcardValue() 
 {
 return cardValue;  
 }

 //toString
 public String toString()
  {
    String output = 
    "The" + rank + "of" + suit + "=" + cardValue + "\n";
    return output;
  }
}
```

This is my runner file:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class CardRunner
{
 public static void main( String args[] )
 {

 Card bob = new Card("ACE", "SPADES", 11); 
 System.out.println(bob.cardValue); 
 }
}
```

Comment: fields in class (when typical class implements getters) should be private, then compiler will give error with Your first loop.
delete "\n" in toString() , use "\n" in external loop

Comment: why upvote for so banal question? I agree, sure not "down". Congratulation that autor give your first attempt, not only "write code for me", but this is too low for "up"

Answer (score 3):

When you call `System.out.println(bob.cardValue);`, you only print the `cardValue` property of your `Card`.

You should print the `Card` instance in order for your `toString` method to be executed :

```
System.out.println(bob);
```

Comment: not property but field, are incorrectly public and this is possible

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output all the data from bob you should do this:

```
System.out.println(bob.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 System.out.println(bob);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `System.out.println(bob.cardValue);` then it prints individual object property.
If you want to print complete object property then pass complete object instead of passing individual property.

print this :-"`System.out.println(bob);` " 
Also you need to override `toString()` function.

```
 //toString
 public String toString()
  {
    String output = 
    "The" + rank + "of" + suit + "=" + cardValue + "\n";
    return output;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote- while you write  `System.out.println(bob.cardValue);` Its printing just exactly that one parameter.

> You need to call your overriden "**toString()**" [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) (btw every object has it, every class, every object in java is children of "*Object*" class)

For calling toString() you don't need to print some parameter of instance **(bob.cardValue)** of some class, but exactly that instance (object) as it **(bob)**  (*bob* is object, instance of "*Card*" class :) ).

Some examples of **toString()** using:

```
System.out.println(bob);  //in fact, will be called toString() also
System.out.println(bob.toString());

//or if you just need save instance in your custom string format in some *String* variable
String bobInMyString = bob.toString();
String bobInMyStringUsingCasttoString = (String) bob; //should also call toString()
```

Btw it should looks like (annotation for compiler):

```
@Override
 public String toString()
  {
    String output = 
    "The" + rank + "of" + suit + "=" + cardValue + "\n";
    return output;
  }
}
```

If you are asking why to use **toString()** override, look eg. on [that very good example](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overriding-tostring-method-in-java/)  (complex numbers), it's usefull for custom classes or for writing object into file, etc.